# Create list of amplitudes from wav files using Python

Tags: python, audio, wav, sliding-window, amplitude

I have a bunch of audio clips of vehicles driving by that I've recorded for an ML experiment.

These 300 or so clips vary in length (4-10 seconds long) and I'd like to clip them to all be a fixed length of 3 seconds, but doing this by hand is a pain in the ass. I want the moment when the car is passing by the microphone (loudest point), and then to clip it 1.5 seconds before and after that moment.

A way I figured how to do this is:

1. Get list of amplitudes for a file
2. Fix a window of 3 seconds long to iterate through list of amplitudes and start at beginning of list, also initialize variables maxAmp and maxIndex to keep track of maximum avg amplitude recorded and the index where that segment begins
3. Average all amplitudes in window, check if greater than max average recorded so far and if it is, replace the max average recorded
4. Move window forward by 1 second
5. Repeat 3 and 4 until we've gone through the file
6. Save audio segment from maxIndex to maxIndex+3seconds after as a new file
7. Do this for all files

This is a really general idea, and I know it isn't exact. I figured taking the average of a window would be better than just finding the location of where the max is and going 1.5 before and after, since the max amplitude might be some wind blowing in the mic at some point in a clip and not actually the sound of the car driving by.

Does this make sense? Is there any way to do it better? What tools/libraries can help me get a list of amplitudes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wavefile` from `scipy.io` to read the WAV file as an array. Then you can put it into a `pandas` data frame to compute the rolling average. Use the `idxmax` function to find the index of the maximum of the rolling average. The data can then be clipped around that index and written into a new WAV file.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
clip_time=3
#fs is the sample rate, so time=samples/fs
[fs,data]=wavfile.read('myRecording.wav','r')
cut_length=fs*3
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['rolling']=df[0].apply(abs).rolling(cut_length).sum()/cut_length
maxIdx=df['rolling'].idxmax()
cut_data=np.array(df[0][maxIdx-cut_length:maxIdx])
wavfile.write('clippedRecording.wav',fs,cut_data)
```